# Comparing Double NOT string value in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, comparison

I am trying to compare latitude and longitude values in sqlite via Android using a BETWEEN operator.  The problem is that the value is always compared as if it's a String and I can't figure out how to compare it as a number.  I found this out because using the query "select * from database orderby latitude" returns a list that is not ordered numerically.  KEY_LAT and KEY_LONG I have stored as both TEXT and REAL, and I get the same output.  Please tell me what info you need.

Here is the query:

```
         double high_lat = curr_lat + 100.0;
     double high_long = curr_longitude + 100.0;
     double low_lat = curr_lat - 100.0;
     double low_long = curr_longitude - 100.0;
         Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME,      new String[]                        {KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ADDR, KEY_LAT, KEY_LONG}, select,
        new String[]
                {KEY_LAT + " BETWEEN " + low_lat + " AND " 
                + high_lat + " AND " + KEY_LONG + " BETWEEN " + low_long + " AND " 
                + high_long},
            null, null, null);
```

Comment: Are you sure your ‘select * from database order by latitude’ returned a list which is ordered neither numerically or alphabetically? I don't think this is possible.

Comment: This should work if the values are in fact stored as REAL.  I would suggest that the actual problem lies with the way you are storing the data, since if you are actually storing the values as numbers it would work.

Comment: Yes antlersoft I'm now storing the values as doubles and now they are ordered properly.  I guess the main problem though had something to do with the select part of the statement.  I used a rawQuery and now it works.  Could you or somebody please give an example of how to form my query using an Android db.query(table, columns[], selection, selection args[]) statement that has multiple selections?  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

Cast your input to REAL as a method of last resort.

`...KEY_LONG + " BETWEEN CAST(" + low_long + " AS REAL) AND CAST(" + high_long +" AS REAL)"`